# Writing a Shell Script to alert me on Mac OS X

Tags: shell-script, filesystems, security, osx

I’m a Mac OS X user and I’m trying to write and run a script that will alert me - or mail me via and inside terminal emulator - whenever a file is created, modified, or changed, for security purposes. I have no idea how to do it and how to start the script since everything on Mac is a bit different than on Linux, since it’s closed. 
I know how I should do it if I want to use it on a certain directory, but I want it for all directories except log files put under `/var/log` and I want it to tell me what’s been changed and where the change was. So checking the bit/bytes to determine the change is useless.

In fact, I want to beware of any change. I know I may face with thousands of changes, but I just want to be kept informed on whatever changing to be sure everything is in the normal situation. In other words, I want to monitor my system data on OS X.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: This would be very annoying. A Unix system is based on files and there would be created and deleted a lot. Especially when you do an upgrade or so.

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could go about this.  You could learn about intrusion detection systems, you could set up puppet, you could write your own script.  If you were to write your own script you would probably want to learn about the md5sum command and maybe use sqlite to store know good values of the file.

Comment: @RedCricket Great, can you just explain a bit more on what I should do and what thing I gotta go for?

Comment: @hschou I know what you say, but what do your recommend? I wanna beware of any change. About a week ago, something appeared to be in my Application directory while I had no idea what the fun it was, and had never seen it before. I’m linux geek, but not that expert in MacOS-related stuff. How should I take care of any change?

Comment: You could probably use [dtrace](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/) for this.

Comment: sounds like you really want a HIDS. Try OSSEC

Comment: Not that it does what you want, but you might like to check out [faeventer](http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/fseventer.html) to get an idea about how many file creation/modifications happen. I've used it in the past to try and see what's happening and often struggle to single out what I want. A lot of changes happen regularly, and this can show you just how much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much pointless. Lots of files are modified on a regular basis. If you exclude all the data files that get modified in normal operation, you're already missing out on some potential attack vectors, and still left with all the normal software upgrades (and upgrades are absolutely necessary, at least, for security). Furthermore an attacker who gains root access can change the system to turn off your detection mechanism, so this is only useful at all if you only monitor files that are not owned by root.

But if you want to do it anyway, use existing software, such as [AIDE](http://aide.sourceforge.net/) (available in [MacPorts](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/security/aide/Portfile)) or [Tripwire](http://www.tripwire.org/) (Google turns up several tutorials for OSX, I can't comment on them).